# Pytorch and Cuda issue: Torch.cuda.is_available() returns false

Tags: python, pytorch, conda

I'm trying to train a deep learning model using my GPU yet only my CPU was in use. I called the cuda is available function and false was returned.
Here's the detail of my python environment.

```
(base) C:\Windows\System32>python -m torch.utils.collect_env
Collecting environment information...
PyTorch version: 2.0.0
Is debug build: False
CUDA used to build PyTorch: Could not collect
ROCM used to build PyTorch: N/A

OS: Microsoft Windows 11 Home
GCC version: Could not collect
Clang version: Could not collect
CMake version: Could not collect
Libc version: N/A

Python version: 3.10.9 | packaged by Anaconda, Inc. | (main, Mar  1 2023, 18:18:15) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] (64-bit runtime)
Python platform: Windows-10-10.0.22621-SP0
Is CUDA available: False
CUDA runtime version: 11.8.89
CUDA_MODULE_LOADING set to: N/A
GPU models and configuration: GPU 0: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4070 Laptop GPU
Nvidia driver version: 531.61
cuDNN version: Could not collect
HIP runtime version: N/A
MIOpen runtime version: N/A
Is XNNPACK available: True

CPU:
Architecture=9
CurrentClockSpeed=2600
DeviceID=CPU0
Family=207

L2CacheSize=4096
L2CacheSpeed=
Manufacturer=GenuineIntel
MaxClockSpeed=2600
Name=13th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-13900H
ProcessorType=3
Revision=

Versions of relevant libraries:
[pip3] mypy-extensions==0.4.3
[pip3] numpy==1.23.5
[pip3] numpydoc==1.5.0
[pip3] pytorch-lightning==2.0.1.post0
[pip3] torch==2.0.0
[pip3] torchaudio==2.0.1+cu118
[pip3] torchmetrics==0.11.4
[pip3] torchvision==0.15.1
[conda] blas                      1.0                         mkl
[conda] cudatoolkit               11.3.1               h59b6b97_2
[conda] mkl                       2021.4.0           haa95532_640
[conda] mkl-service               2.4.0           py310h2bbff1b_0
[conda] mkl_fft                   1.3.1           py310ha0764ea_0
[conda] mkl_random                1.2.2           py310h4ed8f06_0
[conda] numpy                     1.23.5          py310h60c9a35_0
[conda] numpy-base                1.23.5          py310h04254f7_0
[conda] numpydoc                  1.5.0           py310haa95532_0
[conda] pytorch                   2.0.0              py3.10_cpu_0    pytorch
[conda] pytorch-cuda              11.8                 h24eeafa_3    pytorch
[conda] pytorch-lightning         2.0.1.post0              pypi_0    pypi
[conda] pytorch-mutex             1.0                         cpu    pytorch
[conda] torch                     2.0.0                    pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torchaudio                2.0.1+cu118              pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torchmetrics              0.11.4                   pypi_0    pypi
[conda] torchvision               0.15.1                   pypi_0    pypi
```

I had initially downloaded Cuda 12 from nvidia and read that maybe the problem is caused by the newer version of Cuda not being supported. So I downloaded torch and conda using

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda=11.8 -c pytorch -c nvidia
```

It did not solve the issue.

Comment: The conda installed `cudatoolkit` package is 11.3, and the conda installed pytorch and associated packages are 11.8. The fact you have a local version of CUDA 11.8 somewhere probably doesn't matter. The conda managed version is what will be used by the conda managed pytorch install and that is the wrong version from what you have shown

Answer (score 0):

As you can read from your environment:
`CUDA used to build PyTorch: Could not collect`

After checking Pytorch's website it seems that only CUDA 11.7 and 11.8 are supported. Uninstall your CUDA 12, download and install 11.7 / 11.8,   `Conda uninstall pytorch torchvision torchaudio pytorch-cuda` to uninstall Pytroch. Install it again with the matching CUDA version and that should fix your issue.